# Ensure multiple TCP connections use different RX and TX queues and the performance implications?

Tags: performance, optimization, linux-kernel, network-programming, nic

(Linux)

I am considering 2-3 TCP connections using the same network interface card (NIC), but to different IP addresses. Each connection will have its own thread and dedicated CPU core.

I know NICs have multiple receive and transmit queues:

1. How do I ensure each connection has it's own RX and TX queues? Do I need to set any specific socket options, or is this done automatically by the driver/card hashing on the tuple of IP address etc?
2. What are the performance implications of sharing an interface? I presume there will be no contention in the Linux IP/TCP stack? The only contention will be in the hardware as it switches between pushing/popping from a different RX/TX queue? If so, tens of CPU cycles?

Comment: "_I know NICs have multiple receive and transmit queues:_" The hardware has a single FIFO Tx queue. It may be possible to configure several software queues that feed the hardware queue. In any case, only one frame at a time can be transmitted out of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear you need to ensure that each connection has its own RX/TX queue pair on the NIC.  That depends entirely on just how fast each connection will/must go, and how performant your CPUs are relative to those rates.

And, depending on the NIC you have, you may not actually have multiple RX/TX queues exposed to the host.  You can check that with "ethtool -l "